# AFXMLRequestOperation with Google Docs

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-docs-api

I've tried several different approaches to pull content from a google doc with AFNetworking.

1. I've modified the acceptable content types.
2. Used AFKiss functionality
3. Used regular AFHttp operation

Still can't get any content from the following piece of code.  Should be reproducible if anyone has some thoughts.

> NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/0AhNgJb3GRiT3dEFkYmJVQ1pUUXBpdWlOYjFBMUtpOEE/private/full"]];

```
AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
    NSLog(@"Finished");
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSXMLParser *XMLParse) {
    NSLog(@"Failed");
}];
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 1):

View that link in a browser *without being logged in to a Google account*. It doesn't have any content, so you won't be able to load xml regardless of how you try do so.

You'll need to add Google authentication in your app to view the spreadsheet it seems. Information can be found in the [Authenticating Users in Mobile Apps](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps) guide.

Comment: I just clicked that link and there indeed is XML data.

Comment: You are logged into your Google Account. Open it in a fresh browser, without it being logged in (which replicates the request). Empty file.

Comment: Isn't one of the points of using any API that there's some kind of authentication required? I think this is perfectly normal behavior.

Comment: Most of the time, yes. But it's not necessary for all APIs. For viewing Google spreadsheets, it appears to be the case that it's needed.

Comment: Sorry about you're absolutlely right... checked several different browsers which I must have been logged into all of them. Quick and easy way in chrome was to go into incognito mode and try it.  Key point though is making a google doc public only means that it is public to google accounts not world.